# VB equivalent for C#'s default(T)

Tags: vb.net, default-value

What is VB's equivalent for C#'s `default(T)` - the [default operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's any of these:

```
Dim variable As T
Dim variable As T = Nothing
Dim variable As New T()
Dim variable As T = CType(Nothing, T) 'this is suggested by reflector
```

Assigning `Nothing` even to value types is perfectly fine in VB.NET. And the latter is only possible if you specify either `New`, or `Structure` constraint for the generic type.

Comment: Reflector suggests using the following (but equivalent) line:
Dim variable As T = CType(Nothing, T)

Comment: Should anyone wish to confirm the versions here, I slapped together [some code on GitHub](https://github.com/patridge/VB-default-tests) to confirm the results are identical for correct versions. It's a stripped-down console app with a bunch of `Debug.Assert` calls. Just grab and F5 to run.

Answer (score 52):

The closest equivalent to `default(T)` is really `CType(Nothing, T)` since it can be used in any context that `default(T)` is used (i.e. as an expression).

Comment: Doesn't work for the case `If Not id = CType(Nothing, TId) Then...`

Comment: That's value equality. I believe you want `If Not id Is Nothing Then ...`. In this context you don't need to cast the Nothing value.

Comment: MyStructInstance.Equals(ctype(nothing,TypeOfMyStruct)) works. '=' doesn't