# What is the equivalent of C#'s `default` in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I'm normally at home in C#, and I'm looking at a performance issue in some VB.NET code -- I want to be able to compare something to the default value for a type (kind of like C#'s `default` keyword).

```cs
public class GenericThing<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Foo( T2 id )
    {
        if( id != default(T2) ) // There doesn't appear to be an equivalent in VB.NET for this(?)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I was led to believe that `Nothing` was semantically the same, yet if I do:

```vb
Public Class GenericThing(Of T1, T2)
    Public Function Foo( id As T2 ) As T1
        If id IsNot Nothing Then
            ' ...
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Then when `T2` is `Integer`, and the value of `id` is `0`, the condition still passes, and the body of the `if` is evaluated. However if I do:

```vb
    Public Function Bar( id As Integer ) As T1
        If id <> Nothing Then
            ' ...
        End If
    End Function
```

Then the condition is not met, and the body is not evaluated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ VB equivalent for C#'s default(T)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833791/vb-equivalent-for-cs-defaultt)

Comment: @decyclone that question does not cover the generic case; and in fact in my question I show that I know to use `Nothing` in most cases...

Comment: If id.Equals(CType(Nothing, T2)) Then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, as your original C# code doesn't compile. You can use Nothing via a local variable:

```
Public Class GenericThing(Of T)
    Public Sub Foo(id As T)
        Dim defaultValue As T = Nothing
        If id <> defaultValue Then
            Console.WriteLine("Not default")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Default")
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

That doesn't compile, in the same way that the C# version doesn't compile - you can't compare values of unconstrained type parameters like that.

You can use `EqualityComparer(Of T)` though - and then you don't even need the local variable:

```
If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(id, Nothing) Then
```

Comment: I think I took a bit too much business specific terms out of my examples, but that *seems* to work for value types - do you know how well it would work for reference types as well?

Comment: @Rowland: It should be fine as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Well, it's compiling as I type, so I'll soon know for sure; I can see how that would force the compiler to do magic and get it to work

Answer (score 22):

Unlike C#, VB.NET doesn't require a local variable to be initialized with an expression.  It gets initialized to its default value by the runtime.  Just what you need as a substitute for the *default* keyword:

```
    Dim def As T2    '' Get the default value for T2
    If id.Equals(def) Then
       '' etc...
    End If
```

Don't forget the comment, it is going to make somebody go 'Huh?' a year from now.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is the `IsNot` operator, not the `Nothing` keyword.  From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> The IsNot operator determines if two object references refer to different objects. However, it does not perform value comparisons.

You're trying to do a value comparison with a reference operator.  Once you realize this, either Jon Skeet's or Hans Passant's answers become obvious solutions.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - it's always annoys me that VB has both `=` and `Is` for comparisons, with it being up to the developer to know whether to compare value or reference types, respectively.

Comment: @Rowland - C# has an "is" operator also.  I use this rule of thumb that works for both C# and VB: use .Equals() first, if the compiler complains use == / =, and if the compiler still complains use is.

Comment: @Joel/Rowland, habit has me favoring =/== with object/classes.. I tend to use Equals when using nullable types (Guid?,DateTime?, etc).  I come across a lot of code that treats Guids improperly (as strings) instead of Guid? ... it actually irks me more in SQL when I have to use is null, where = null will usually bork what I am trying to do.