# What is the equivalent to C# default literal for a struct in VB?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, struct, default

i stumbled across this C# code `return default;` in a method with a struct as return type.
The closest translation to the default literal i have come across for VB is `Return CType(Nothing, T)` - however, VS is suggesting to replace this expression with nothing.
Since my T is of struct (and therefore a value type which

> the default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to `null`)

i was wondering what the best equivalent in VB for that would be.

Thank you in advance and best regards!

Comment: I assume you mean by "suggesting to replace this expression with nothing" you mean that VS is suggesting to replace `CType(Nothing, T)` with `Nothing`.  This should be a valid substitution (also see the suggested duplicate).

Comment: According to [Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values): _struct: The value produced by setting all value-type fields to their default values and all reference-type fields to null._

Comment: I can't believe i couldn't find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833791/vb-equivalent-for-cs-defaultt myself. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, 'Nothing' will give you the same results as 'CType(Nothing, T)', however in other cases you lose information.
e.g.,

```
Dim test1 = CType(Nothing, Foo)
Dim test2 = Nothing
```

The first local 'test1' if of type Foo, but the second is of type 'Object'. This will also affect expressions where the compiler knowing the actual type of a sub-expression changes the result of the expression. For this reason, I doubt if VS will always recommend the use of 'Nothing' over 'CType(Nothing, Foo)'. If in doubt, use the more verbose syntax to avoid loss of information.

Comment: Re your differences, this is especially important for the case where `Foo` is a value type.  In that case, `test1` will be valid to use from a language point of view (if not necessarily from a domain point of view) whereas trying to access anything on `test2` will lead to a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

> i was wondering what the best equivalent in VB for that would be.

Yes, in your case `Return Nothing` would be the appropriate replacement.

In general:

1. `default` corresponds to `Nothing`, and
2. `default(T)` corresponds to `CType(Nothing, T)`.

The first is for situations where the compiler can be infer the type from context, and the second one for all other situations.